# How can I apply `noqa` in order to ignore warning messages when lsp-mode is enabled

Tags: flycheck, warning, lsp

I am trying to ignore flycheck warning messages, when `lsp-mode` for the `python-mode` is on. I have tried `["# noqa", "# NOQA", "# flake8: noqa", "# type: ignore"]` but neither of them seems working.

[image]

---

I am totaly lost how I can fix this .

Installation from https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server

`pip install 'python-lsp-server[all]'`

my basic configuration is as follows:

```lisp
(require 'package)
(setq user-init-file (or load-file-name (buffer-file-name)))
(setq user-emacs-directory (file-name-directory user-init-file))

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(setq frame-background-mode 'dark)
(defun flycheck-python-setup ()
  (flycheck-mode))
(require 'flycheck)
(require 'flycheck-mypy)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
(add-to-list 'flycheck-disabled-checkers 'python-flake8)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq flycheck-python-pylint-executable "~/venv/bin/pylint")
            (setq flycheck-pylintrc "~/.pylintrc")
            (setq indent-tabs-mode  nil
                  python-indent-offset  4
                  tab-width         4)
            (let ((inhibit-message  t))
              )))
(use-package python :ensure nil)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'flycheck-python-setup)
(flycheck-add-next-checker 'python-flake8 'python-pylint 'python-mypy)

(require 'lsp-pylsp)
(setq lsp-pylsp-plugins-pylint-args ["--rcfile=~/.pylintrc"])
(setq lsp-pylsp-plugins-pylint-enabled t)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'lsp)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'lsp-deferred)
(setq lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable nil)
(setq lsp-enable-symbol-highlighting nil)
(setq lsp-modeline-diagnostics-enable 1)
(setq lsp-ui-doc-enable nil)
(setq lsp-lens-enable nil)
(setq lsp-pyls-plugins-pylint-enabled nil)
(setq lsp-ui-sideline-enable nil)
(setq lsp-ui-sideline-show-diagnostics nil)
(setq lsp-log-io nil) ; if set to true can cause a performance hit
(setq lsp-enable-snippet nil)  ;; solves to prevent () to be added during completions
(setq lsp-file-watch-threshold 2000)
(setq lsp-idle-delay 0.500)
(setq read-process-output-max (* 1024 1024)) ;; 1mb
(setq gc-cons-threshold 402653184
      gc-cons-percentage 0.6)
```

Please note that `# noqa` works if `lsp` is disabled.

Comment: Not all language-servers (or linters) respect `#noqa`. Make sure your language server is configured correctly and required plugins are loaded. Or use a language server that you know respects `#noqa`.

Comment: @neqa I am using `# noqa` only for Python, not any other language. How could I configure python-language server correctly? When I check `cmd-c-!-v` all plugins seems loaded

Comment: I don't know how you could configure your language server correctly since you haven't told us which python language server you're using. I can think of at least 5 python language servers off the top of my head, and I'd bet 30 seconds of googling will add 3 more. I'm going to _guess_ that you're using [Douglas Davis's `lsp-pylsp`](https://github.com/douglasdavis/lsp-pylsp) which was integrated into [`lsp-mode`](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode) earlier this year. Reading that `.el` file ...

Comment: ... you learn that it's designed to use the [Spyder IDE python-language-server](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server). I would suggest you start with that project's README.

Comment: Additionally, you add `'python-flake8` to `flycheck-disabled-checkers`, then later you use `'python-flake8` as an argument to `flycheck-add-next-checker`. Does that combination _actually do_ what you think it does?

Comment: I have added my configuration related to `lsp`, For the `flycheck-disabled-checkers` I have tried multiple combinations but non of them seems working ex only using `flake8` or only `python-mypy` .  // Please note that I have installed it using `pip install 'python-lsp-server[all]'` from https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server

Comment: @alper, I think you have a typing mistake - I do not use ```broker``` module, but find out only one on GitHub, that having a ```*helpers*``` sub-module, not ```helper```. Verify this with terminal command ```pydoc broker``` (if you do not have pydoc installed, then install with pip).

Comment: @nega, the python-language-server is *maintained* by Spider IDE team; if they use it for Spider is another story.

Comment: Then what about your first code line in posted picture: ```from broker.helper import helper```? are you sure you have it? not found even with ```fd```? If not found then where to import something? otherwise you are soothing in vain with #noqa.

Comment: Ah it was just name of my of module. Similiar example could be done for `import os; import os; import os`... sorry for confusion, or any warning message is given by the python lsp-flycheck. I have updated my question with `import os` to be more general. The warning message shows up if I re-imported the same module name, I just used it to give an example

Comment: thanks @ian, that's perfectly clear in the about section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

When trying to figure anything out, simplify!

```
$ pip3 install 'pyparsing<3'
$ pip3 install python-lsp-server
# use a minimal `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, such as the one listed below
```

Here's my recipe to get `lsp-mode`+`python-lsp-server` working with `flycheck`.

### `python-lsp-server`

First we need an lsp server for Python. Following the instructions at https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server#installation I attempted to install `python-lsp-server`

```
$ pip3 install python-lsp-server
```

Installation failed, because `pip3` wanted to install `pyparsing v3.0.5` while `python-lsp-server` wanted `'pyparsing<3,>=2.0.2'`. This was easily remedied.

```
$ pip3 install 'pyparsing<3'
$ pip3 install python-lsp-server
```

### `lsp-mode` + `flycheck`

Next I created a *fresh* `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, and following the instructions at https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/installation/#use-package I added the recommended `use-package` form. Also, by adding setup for `flycheck` this gives me a *minimal init file* of:

```lisp
;; -*- mode: emacs-lisp; ; indent-tabs-mode: nil -*-

;; Bootstrap package.el
(require 'package)
(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
             '("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

;; Bootstrap 'use-package'
(eval-after-load 'gnutls
  '(add-to-list 'gnutls-trustfiles "/etc/ssl/cert.pem"))
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
(require 'bind-key)
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)

;; setup flycheck
(use-package flycheck
  :config (global-flycheck-mode))

;; setup lsp-mode, https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/installation/#use-package
(use-package lsp-mode
  :init
  ;; set prefix for lsp-command-keymap (few alternatives - "C-l", "C-c l")
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")
  :hook (;; replace XXX-mode with concrete major-mode(e. g. python-mode)
         (python-mode . lsp)
         ;; if you want which-key integration
         (lsp-mode . lsp-enable-which-key-integration))
  :commands lsp)
```

### Sample python file

Now we need a sample python file with known style errors.

```
$ cat > ~/foo/foo.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os,sys

example = lambda: 'example'
^D
$
```

### Editing our python file

Now we get to work...

```
$ emacs ~/foo/foo.py
```

`lsp-mode` asks us what we want to do..

[image: lsp-mode import dialog]

Naturally, we want to import our new file, so we hit <kbd>i</kbd>, and `lsp-mode` lets us know it has successfully imported our file.

[image: lsp-mode notification of successful import]

Now, you'll notice that our file has `flycheck`'s familiar arrows and squiggles.

[image: emacs window with python code and linter error symbols]

If we add `# noqa` to line #5, you'll see its squiggle, and error listing, are gone.

[image: emacs window with python code and linter error symbols, showing the effect of # noqa to a line of code in order to skip linting]

You may also have noticed that the "Checker" in `*Flycheck errors*` is "lsp". *This is what we want*. If you want `flake8` to be the primary checker, you can select it for the current session via <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>!</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, selecting "python-flake8", and hitting <kbd>q</kbd> to close the selection window. When back at your `foo.py` window, run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `flycheck-error-list-reset-filter`. You'll notice that line #5 continues to be "error free".

[image: similar as the previous image, but using flycheck's python-flake8 checker]

### Now what?

Continue to build up your configuration until something strange or unexpected happens. Stop. Undo that last change. Read the documentation of what you added and figure out what you did wrong. *Do not* blindly add more and more to your configuration, and dig yourself a deeper hole.

Comment: I have tried your exact code with a python file: `emacs -Q -nw -l ~/home/emacs_lsp.el ~/test.py` but I am still seeing warning message for the lines that has `# noqa`. I am using `python-lsp-server==1.3.3` and `pyparsing==2.4.7`

Comment: _worksforme_... make sure your subordinate tools (`pycodestyle`, `flake8`, etc.) *are not ignoring* `# noqa`. see those respective tools' documentation.

Comment: How could they ignore `# noqa`?  I have `pycodestyle==2.8.0` and `flake8==4.0.1` // I have also `~/.pylintrc`  and `~/.config/flake8` file. Don't they automatically ignore `# noqa`?

Comment: How can I prevent `pycodestyle`, `flake8` from ignoring the `# noqa`? I have applied your solution but it did not detect `# noqa` to ignore warning messages